# Plotting a parabola - NotImplementedError

Tags: python, plot

[Problem statement and attempt at problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ehpl.png)

I'm trying to write code for the given problem, but I keep receiving a "NotImplementedError" and I don't understand what this means or how to fix my code to resolve this error.

Comment: sharing your code and the call trace would be more helpful to help you

Comment: You can access both through the blue link, "Problem statement and attempt at problem"

Comment: your code is fine, it's just that the `figure()` function is not implemented in `blockpy`, try without it it's going to work

Comment: Wow. Teaching `range` and Matplotlib in the same tutorial. Good job on writing almost perfect code OP, but I have a bad feeling about the quality of the tutorial you are using, if that's what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `figure()` function is not implemented in `BlockPy` you can try ploting your parabola without instantiating a figure,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = b = list()
for x in range(100):
    y = 10 * x - x*x
    a.append(x)
    b.append(y)

plt.plot(a, b)
plt.show()
```

hope this helps!!